# DEBUG Logging Causes StackOverflowError in Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot

I recently upgraded my Spring Boot app from 1.5.10 to 2.0.3 and am now facing this issue: when I add `logging.level.root=DEBUG` to my `application.properties`, I get the following exception:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "background-preinit" java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)
  at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:293)
  at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
  at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
  at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:931)
  at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:180)
  at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.debug(DirectJDKLog.java:103)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1154)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
  at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)
  at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:293)
  at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
  at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
  at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:931)
  at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:180)
  at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.debug(DirectJDKLog.java:103)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1154)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
  at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)
  at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:293)
  ...
```

This is only a small portion, as this set of the stack trace repeats over 100 times, causing the `StackOverflowError`.

Debugging steps I've tried:

- If I change the logging level to anything else, like `INFO`, I don't get the exception.
- I've added a specific dependency for `SLF4JBridgeHandler` in my `pom.xml`.
- I've made sure that `SLF4JBridgeHandler` is on the classpath of my web app.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: what is the version of your slf4j? do you configure them manually in pom.xml? If yes, could you show us the pom.xml as well?

Comment: Add `logging.level.org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog=INFO`

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan the `slf4j-api` jar is version `1.7.25` and is imported from my `spring-security-saml-dsl-core` dependency.

Comment: Looks like your slf4j is trying to redirect the logging to java.util.logging and it again redirects logging to slf4j causing an infinite loop. I think I read this some where in the docs... Wait

Comment: @Andreas I've added it, got the same exception, no new output was created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll just quote the [official slf4j documentation](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j),

> **jul-to-slf4j.jar and slf4j-jdk14.jar cannot be present simultaneously**
>
> The presence of `slf4j-jdk14.jar`, that is the `jul` binding for
>   `SLF4J`, will force `SLF4J` calls to be delegated to `jul`. On the
>   other hand, the presence of `jul-to-slf4j.jar`, plus the installation
>   of `SLF4JBridgeHandler`, by invoking "`SLF4JBridgeHandler.install()`"
>   will route `jul` records to `SLF4J`. Thus, if both jar are present
>   simultaneously (and `SLF4JBridgeHandler` is installed), `slf4j` calls
>   will be delegated to `jul` and `jul` records will be routed to
>   `SLF4J`, resulting in an endless loop.

Which is what is happening to your case.

---

Try doing `mvn dependency:tree` and exclude the conflicting dependencies.

In my opinion, `spring-boot` is good at managing dependencies like this. So its good to keep the `pom.xml` clean with less manually added dependencies.

Comment: That worked! Had a dependency to `jul-to-slf4j.jar` in my `pom.xml` which was causing the issue. Removed the dependency, ran `mvn clean package`, and was good to go!

Comment: Also, could you include a link to the full documentation you pulled that excerpt from?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone's search for `java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14` led to this question.

The root cause is already explained in Raja's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484475/1113392).

In my case it was the mockserver dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockserver-netty-no-dependencies</artifactId>
   <version>5.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Which had the classes from slf4j/jul bundled inside it, which resulted in the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:167)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:979)
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.innerNormalizedLoggingCallHandler(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:156)
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:172)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:979)
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.innerNormalizedLoggingCallHandler(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:156)
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:172)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
```

As the those classes were not inside a transitive dependency an exclusion was not possible. So the solution was just to replace the mentioned dependency with all denepndies required to run mockserver, again in my case

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockserver-netty</artifactId>
   <version>5.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```